# K8S Autoscaling trigger Cloud Function

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, autoscaling

Is it possible to trigger Pub/Sub event or Google Cloud Function in the GCloud, when my Node pool is auto-scaling under high performance conditions?

Or is there any other analytics event which can be used to trigger Cloud Function?

Comment: How is this question related to programming? It might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be notified (in Pub/Sub) when a node pool is scaled up by setting a [sink on Stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export), with a Pub/Sub topic as destination.

You have to listen to specific logs corresponding to the scale up of your node pool. There are 2 filters you can use for your sink. Any message corresponding to one of these filter will be sent to a Pub/Sub topic, meaning that you can then have a Cloud Function triggered when a message is published in that topic.

#### Filter on instance group

You can use this filter on instance group (a GKE node pool is in fact a managed instance group of Compute VMs) :

```
resource.type="gce_instance_group_manager" AND
resource.labels.instance_group_manager_name:"gke-<cluster_name>-default-pool" AND
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instanceGroupManagers.resize" AND
operation.last="true"
```

(please replace `<cluster_name>` with the name of your cluster, and `<node_pool_name>` with the node pool name, like `default-pool`).

#### Filter on cluster autoscaler logs

You can also use this filter :

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster" AND
logName="projects/<project_id>/logs/container.googleapis.com%2Fcluster-autoscaler-visibility" AND
jsonPayload.decision.scaleUp.increasedMigs.mig.nodepool="<node_pool_name>"
```

(please replace `<project_id>` with the id of your project, and `<node_pool_name>` to the node pool name, like `default-pool`).

What's interesting with this filter is that you can know which pod have caused the scale up, and how many nodes have been added, by looking inside the `jsonPayload` :

```
jsonPayload: {
    decision: {
        eventId: "41ddc559-c616-4068-8ba2-2f26eadcc7bd"
        decideTime: "1620897027"
        scaleUp: {
            increasedMigs: [
                0: {
                    mig: {
                        name: "gke-<cluster_name>-<node_pool_name>-xxxxxxxx-grp"
                        nodepool: "<node_pool_name>"
                        zone: "<zone>"
                    }
                    requestedNodes: 1
                }
            ]
            triggeringPods: [
                0: {
                    name: "<pod_name_causing_the_scale_up>"
                    namespace: "<pod_namespace>"
                }
            ]
            triggeringPodsTotalCount: 1
        }
    }
}
```